# How to notify a define in puppet

Tags: puppet, notify

EDIT: I am editing this based on the suggestions below:

I have a definition like this in a module called symfony2:

```
define symfony2::symfony2($cache = false, $root_dir = '') {
    if $cache {
        file {"${root_dir}/app/cache":
            path => "${root_dir}/app/cache",
            ensure => directory,
            purge => true,
            force => true,
        }
    }
}
```

Then I instantiate this define in my script like so:

```
symfony2::symfony2{"symfony2":
    cache => true,
    root_dir => "/home/whatever",
}
```

and I want it to get called upon a notify of this exec resource, but I can't find any information describing how to do it:

```
exec {"do-something-and-then-notify-the-symfony2-define":
    command => "xyz...",
    notify => symfony2::Symfony2["symfony2"],
}
```

The notify => Symfony2 part is my problem. How do I script this to have the exec notify the symfony2 definition? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this :

```
exec {"do-something-and-then-notify-the-symfony2-define":
command => "xyz...",
notify => ModuleName::Symfony2["symfony2"],
}
```

btw, what error are you getting when you tried what you tried ?

Comment: Thanks! I did that (I edited the code above to reflect the changes I made). I also fully qualified the definition by prepending "symfony2::' to it. Now this gives the following error: "Syntax error at '::Symfony2'; expected '}' at ...followed by the file name and line number.

Comment: Yes, that was no problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your resource reference `symfony2::Symfony2["symfony2"]` you should uppercase the first letter of each type reference, so `Symfony2::Symfony2["symfony2"]`.

Here is proof that this works:

```
define foo::bar() {
  notify { $title: }
}
foo::bar { 'first': }
notify { "second":
   notify => Foo::Bar['first']
}
```

Produces `first` and `second` in the right order.

Comment: That was the missing piece! Thanks! I accepted iamauser's answer though, because his answer got me really close and it was my fault I didn't make the first letter capital. I upvoted your answer, though. :)